# rtl_433 on raspberry pi: Send data to api via http post

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, http, raspberry-pi, rtl-sdr

I'm receiving the weather data from my weather station with a dongle on my raspberry pi, that has internet connection via wifi. Now I want to send this data to a rails api/app to save it there in a database. The rails app runs on another server, so I want to post the data via http.
How can I do this. I can't add the curl dependency to the rtl_433 project (https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433) to send the data directly to my backend. Am I able to run the rtl_433 for example with a python script like: 
 `rlt_433 -F json` and take that output to send it to my backend or how can I realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it now out, how to get the data from the subprocess and listen to it **all the time**:

1. I installed `python 3.8` to use the `datetime` library correctly. This approach is supported with `version >= python 3.7`
2. I created a python script, taht is listening to the output of my `rtl_433` command.
   As you can see I'm using: `rtl_433 -f 868.300M -F json`.

here is my `listener.py`:

```py
import subprocess
import json
import datetime
from threading import Thread

def parse(printed_text):
    # here you can parse your string input from the subprocess

# sending to api
def sendToApi(text):
    parsed_json = parse(text)
    result = <send_to_api(parsed_json)> # here your http.post
    print(result)

# This method creates a subprocess with subprocess.Popen and takes a List<str> as command
def execute(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line 
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)

for json in execute(['/path/to/rtl_433/build/src/rtl_433', '-f','868.300M', '-F', 'json']):
    print(text, end="")
    # I'm starting a new thread to avoid data loss. So I can listen to the weather station's output and send it async to the api
    thread = Thread(target = sendToApi, args = (text,))
    thread.start()
```

after that I can use:

`python3.8 listener.py` and get all the data that is sent by the weather station

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to execute `rtl_433` as a subprocess using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. Normally you would just use `subprocess.run`, but since `rtl_433` produces output until it is killed, you will need to use `subprocess.Popen` and parse the output.

Another option is to pipe the output of `rtl_433` to your program and using `input()` or `sys.stdin.readline()` to read lines. Like `rtl_433 -flags | python3 script.py`.

Comment: Thx! I checked it out and it works. After this, I create a dict and send the post with requests import and arguments url and json ;)

Comment: Nice! I'm curious, did you go with the subprocess approach or the pipe approach?

Comment: I used pipe: rtl_433 -flags | python3 data_poster.py and there with sys.stdin.readline()

Comment: ok, I have antoher problem and didn't get time for it:
I got it to work with `cat text.json | python weather_poster.py`, but if I try to run rtl_433 -F json | weather_poster.py I only get a _io.TextIOWrapper object and can't do anything with this...
Any solutions?

`subprocess.Popen(["rtl_433", "-F", "json"], subprocess.PIPE)` doesn't work to...